# Same-origin policy in react, Why is this working though?

Tags: reactjs, same-origin-policy

It's my first question in here (after years of browsing the site).

I've found a plunger with a react component loading an iframe and allowing change the source of the iframe to another origin.

Plunger Link: http://plnkr.co/edit/GRkvbJssZbWDWLfjHB7i?p=preview

```
 var Componentnt = React.createClass({

 render: function() {
  var Iframe = this.props.iframe;

 return (

  < div >

  < Iframe src = {
    this.props.src
  }
  height = {
    this.props.height
  }
  width = {
    this.props.width
  }
  />

  < /div>
)
}
});
ReactDOM.render(
 //Change this to https://www.cnn.com/
 < Componentnt iframe = 'iframe'
 src = "https://www.usatoday.com/"
 height = "500px"
 width = "100%" / > ,
 document.getElementById('example')
);`
```

According to the same origin policy, isn't supposed to prevent the change of the iframe source because of this?

If anyone can explain this for me, that would be great.

Thank you everyone!

Comment: well, no, the iframe is in your document, you can change what page it is including all you want. You just can't access the contents of said page.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer, I now understand a little more about that. Now, having in account that, why if I try to change the source of the Iframe to some sites, It gives me an `Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.` I need to specify something in the destination site?

Comment: Change in what way?

Comment: So, I was trying to insert in the iframe a source that in a init function of a script inside the source is doing top.window.location, so probably is breaking the site because, according to cross-browser policy that is not allowed. Is that right? Thank you for you help!

Comment: yeah you cant touch the iframe's contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the iframe page content, add your domain to the document as follow to get access.

```
<script>
 document.domain = 'external-domain.tld'
</script>
```